# Closure memory leak and fix

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, closures

Going through [Mozilla's A re-introduction to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Memory_leaks), the following code causes a memory leak:

```
function addHandler() {
  var el = document.getElementById('el');
  el.onclick = function() {
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  };
}
```

Would the following revised code not cause a memory leak because `el` is not being referenced inside the `onclick` function?

```
function addHandler() {
  var el = document.getElementById('el');
  el.onclick = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  };
}
```

Comment: You're still currying a variable, `this` in this case, if that's what you're asking. Also make sure you understand the difference between `this` and `self`.

Comment: Thanks goodness that there will be no Internet Explorer anymore soon. Nowadays browsers can handle garbage collection in civilized manner.

Comment: that code cause a leak in IE only, the IE that was out when the article was written years ago. don't worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes memory leaks will be prevented, and you can be even more concise by ditching the local variable `el` and directly assign the `onclick` property of the element:

```
function addHandler(){
  document.getElementById('el').onclick = function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  };
}
```

So, inside the `onclick` callback, `this` references the element itself on which the click event was performed, so it's trivial to use `this` in order to set the style (i.e. `backgroundColor`) on the element when clicked.